# Return the most relevant columns for a given keyword

Tags: word2vec, semantic-similarity

Suppose my database has column name and description for each column of each table. Need to design an interface where a user can enter a keyword and the interface will return the most relevance columns. For example, enter "payment" and the interface can just find and return a list of columns containing "payment" in column name and description. But what if the user enters a keyword doesn't exist in column name and description, then how to suggest the most relevant columns for this keyword? Any suggestions?

Comment: you should have a corpus of related words/synonyms

Comment: @NikosM. Ok, if I use column name and description as corpus, what to do next to get what I want?

Comment: If the column names and descriptions are enough then you are fine, else you can have an additional corpus of related words/synonyms (that map to column names) the user might use and which are not lexicaly related to column names